# Alsa amixer lists both playback and capture device when using softvol

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

I'm using alsa with dmix and softvol to mix multiple sound sources and control their individual volumes. This works but there is a thing that's bothering me. The mixer control show When i play back a wave file with aplay. But the description mentions a playback and a capture channel but i want to use separate controls for both playback and capture. This is my amixer output:

```
Simple mixer control 'SpeechPlayback',0
  Capabilities: volume volume-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Capture channels: Mono
  Limits: 0 - 255
  Mono: 255 [100%]
```

This is the .asoundrc I use:

```
pcm.!default pcm.snd_card0

pcm.snd_card0 {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}
ctl.snd_card0 {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}

pcm.dmix0 {
    type dmix
    ipc_key 1024
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    slave.pcm "snd_card0"
    slave {
    period_time 0
    period_size 256
    rate 44100
    format S16_LE
    }
}
ctl.dmix0 {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}

pcm.dsnoop0 {
    type dsnoop
    ipc_key 2048
    ipc_key_add_uid true
    slave.pcm "snd_card0"
    slave {
    period_time 0
    period_size 256
    rate 8000
    }
}

ctl.dsnoop0 {
    type hw
    card 0
    device 0
}

############################################################################
# Volume controls for the different PCM devices
# controls become available after first playback
# volume e.g.:  amixer set Ring 80%
############################################################################
pcm.ring {
    type plug
    slave{
    channels 1
    rate 44100
    pcm{
        type softvol    
        slave.pcm "dmix0"
        control {
        name "Ring"
        count 1
        }
    }
    }
}

pcm.speech_play {
    type plug
    slave{
    channels 1
    rate 44100
    pcm{
        type softvol    
        slave.pcm "dmix0"
        control {
        name "SpeechPlayback"
        count 1
        }
    }
    }
}

pcm.speech_capture {
    type plug
    slave{
    channels 1
    rate 8000
    pcm{
        type softvol    
        slave.pcm "dsnoop0"
        control {
        name "SpeechCapture"
        count 1
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Is there anybody who knows how to separate the playback from the capture controls. I have tried asym but could not find a configuration that works for me.

Best regards,
Jeroen van der Laan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The naming of the control determines its direction renaming "Ring" to "Ring Playback Volume" ill create a ring control with only a playback option.

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly! To create only a capture control,  should the name be "Speech Capture Volume"? I hope you can remember :)

Comment: Update: I just tried it and my assumption was correct. "Speech Capture Volume" will create only a capture volume control with the name Speech.